# Killing msiexec from all users

Tags: c#, process, cmd, windows-installer

I have a winform app that installs msi drivers. I want the user to have a "cancel downloads" button.
I tried many ways to do the killing in different ways and with no success.

using:

```
    Process[] processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("msiexec.exe");
    foreach (Process process in processesByName)
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
```

It gave me "Win32Exception access is denied".

I tried to do that from cmd, so i could use it in the code as Process.Start("cmd", "taskkill....."), but that gave me an odd answer:

```
C:\>taskkill /IM msiexec.exe
ERROR: The process "msiexec.exe" not found.
```

Of course, I still see it in my task manager.
I think my problem is that the msiexec.exe is under SYSTEM user and not under my current user, but using the taskkill from a specific user gave me:

```
C:\>TASKKILL /F /FI "USERNAME eq NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /IM msiexec.exe
INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria.
```

Any help on how to kill all msiexec processes from all users?

Comment: Arbitrarily killing the windows installer service could have a very adverse impact on the system.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

As Christopher said is not recommended to try stopping a system service. Instead you could cancel your install with a small [custom action that returns ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: My app is running few msi one after another, I just want the user to be able to cancel all the installations without have to press the Cancel button on each msi windows installer.